# Why is the aggregate mediator is not working after the Iterator(for construction an json payload using Payload factory) WSO2 7.2.0 (mi-4.0.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

When i was trying to construct an JSON payload by Iterating the JSON array by using Iterator and extracting the specific field from the payload and trying to form an Json Payload by using Payload factory inside an Iterator after Iterator i was trying to set an aggregate mediator to aggregate all the json response and trying to set into the context for transformation and responding back to the Client

Sequence for generation of Desired Output by using Iterator with Aggregate mediator

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="AGGREGATE_CHECK" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//Customers" id="line-Item-Iterator" sequential="true">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <property expression="//Name" name="Name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//DOJ" name="Doj" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                    <format>{
                            "NAME": "$1",
                            "DOJ": $2,
                            }</format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Name"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Doj"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <log level="full"/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <log>
        <property name="after iterator" value="coming out for aggregator"/>
    </log>
    <aggregate id="line-Item-Iterator">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" expression="json-eval($)">
            <property expression="$body/*" name="response" scope="operation" type="OM"/>
            <log level="full"/>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('operation','response')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log>
        <property expression="$body/*" name="Aggregated-response"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
`
```

Note:

1. If I try to log the response inside the iterator logging is happening with the proper output payload
2. Tried by changing the continueParent in iterate mediator to false as well no proper output
3. If I tried logging inside the onComplete  block we are not getting any logs inside the Aggregate mediator
   Needed help to understand this issue and solve it
   Thanks in Advance
   [image]

INPUT PAYLOAD

```
`{
    "data": {
        "level": "asss",
        "Info": {
            "Customers": [
                [
                    {
                        "Name": "Ram",
                        "Age": 26,
                        "city": "TX",
                        "DOJ": "26-06-2002"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Shri",
                        "Age": 29,
                        "city": "TX",
                        "DOJ": "12-06-1999"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Reena",
                        "Age": 25,
                        "city": "TX",
                        "DOJ": "22-06-2007"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "ms": {}
}`
```

excepted output

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Ram",
        "DOJ": "26-06-2002"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Shri",
        "DOJ": "12-06-1999"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Reena",
        "DOJ": "22-06-2007"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate Mediator should be used when you are calling a Backend in each iteration cycle. You should be using the `Foreach Mediator` if you just want to Iterate over a payload.

Having said that, for the mentioned usecase you don't really need to Iterate the Payload. You can simply use the Enrich Mediator to remove the elements you don't need.

```xml
<enrich>
    <source clone="false" xpath="json-eval($.[*].city,$.[*].Age)"/>
    <target action="remove" type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

---

**Update**

Here is the for-each solution. You can't use the aggregate mediator with the Foreach Mediator. Foreach Mediator will automatically append the Payload to its parent element.

```xml
<foreach expression="json-eval($)" id="1">
    <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{
                "NAME": "$1",
                "DOJ": "$2"
                }
                </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Name"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.DOJ"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

---

**Update 02**
There are different ways to do this, the following is one way. Another way is having the Enrich after the foreach and removing the parent element.

```xml
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" xpath="json-eval($.data.Info.Customers[0])"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
<foreach expression="json-eval($)" id="1">
    <sequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{
                "NAME": "$1",
                "DOJ": "$2"
                }
                </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Name"/>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.DOJ"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

Comment: This use case I've added as an sample response but we are getting more that 10 fields
so that we need to construct an json array for particular two fileds
that case we are trying to Foreach Mediator as well after that aggregating the response is not happening as excepted can you please guide me why we are facing issue with aggregator

Comment: @sathishSankarzz It doesn't really matter how many fields there are as long as you simply want to remove them. So are you doing any modifications to the values or field names?

Comment: yeah we may modify field name as well that is the reason we are setting an payload factory inside iterator or for each mediator

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
This was tightly coupled with the exact  Input payload whatever shared earlier
for that  it was working fine but on an high level I've shared my exact input payload
can you check my updated Input Payload for that i was not able to get the proper response as excepted